# How do I make my navigation bar lead to another page?

Tags: html, css, navbar, brackets

So I'm REALLY new to HTML and brackets, however I have a little navigation bar going. That's pretty much it. What I want to ask is, how do I make it so when I press one of the buttons in the bar, that button leads to another page? This is the code:

Index.html:

```
    <DOCTYPE Html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Navigation Bar</title> 
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>  
<body>
<div id="Maindiv">
   <div id="navdiv">

        <u1>
            <h1>The Turtle House</h1>
             <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Information</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Care Guide</a></li>
       </u1>
    </div>    
</div>   
</body>
</html>
```

Style.css:

```
body{
    font-family: arial, sans-serif;

}
*{
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
}
#maindiv{
    width: 100%;
    height: 1000px;
    background: url(img/RiverRock.jpg) repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}
#navdiv u1{
    width: 100%;
    height: 80px;
    background: #648DA0;
    line-height: 80px;
    color: white;
    float: right;
}
#navdiv u1 a{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
    padding: 20px;
}
#navdiv u1 li {
    list-style-type: none;
    display: inline-block;
    float: right;
}
#navdiv u1 li:hover{
    background: #8FB0BF;
    transition:all 0.40s;
}
#navdiv h1{
    width: 300px;
    float: left;
    cursor: pointer;
    margin-left: 15px;
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a#Linking_to_an_external_location

Comment: Adding a link path instead of `#` would solve your issue. for example `<a href="otherPage.html">Contact</a>`

Comment: You really should get a book or find a tutorial on the web like [this Khan Academy track](https://www.khanacademy.org/computing/computer-programming/html-css) to learn the basics of web development.

Answer (score 1):

Put the page name in the anchor link href:

```
<li><a href="Contact.html">Contact</a></li>
```

Comment: How exactly do I get a page name?

Comment: Create a file and name it.